How is a cone most often (or by convention) notated to show its exact shape?
Should the exact shape be notated by the angle $\theta$ in the circular sector of its net, the slope of the slant height $\Bigl(\frac{\text{height}}{\text{radius}}\Bigr)$, or the arccotangent of the slope $\phi$?  I'd only read about examples naming a cone after $\theta$ but was curious what the general consensus is.


What you say net is more commonly referred to as its  development (in English).

"Should the exact shape be notated by ... ?" ... "Should" is a tricky word. In general, you "should" use whatever defining measure suits your purpose. I personally favor the angle $\phi$ (sometimes $2\phi$, sometimes $90^\circ-\phi$), as it's immediately geometrically meaningful. Who thinks of a cone primarily as its net? I couldn't be bothered to unroll a cone to determine $\theta$ as a defining measure; to me, it's the least useful of all the measurements in the cone ... unless/until you want to find the surface area, or to build the cone from paper, when it comes in pretty handy. :)

The circular cone given ( base radius, height) is commonly and fully understood.
Respectively with the above $(r,h)$ are derived slant height slope angle ( generator angle ) a.k.a. the semi vertical angle $ \phi$
$$ \phi=\tan^{-1}\frac{r}{h}=\sin^{-1}\frac{r}{s},$$
and sector development central angle $\theta$:
$$~ \theta= \frac {2 \pi r}{s}.$$

I know how they're calculated, I just wanted to know which one is used for reference by default.
